# PDO, can't delete the selected record

Tags: php, pdo

i'm having a problem when i try to delete the record which i select in my menu page, after i click delete,the header shows me that the record has been deleted, as well it shows me the message=deleted , but i realize that the record still appear in my menu page, and i also checked the phpmyadmin and it also still exists, i think i'm not reach the selected record in the delete page, here's my code so far :
delete.php

```
    <?php
    include('koneksi.php');
    $page_number = $_GET['page'];
   <?php
include('koneksi.php');
$page_number = $_GET['page'];
                  $dbdit = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=laundry','root','');
                  $results = $dbdit->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM konsumen");
                  $results->execute();
                  $get_total_rows = $results->fetch();
                  $results = $dbdit->prepare("DELETE FROM konsumen ORDER BY kode_pemesanan ASC LIMIT :page_number");
                  $results->bindValue(':page_number',$page_number);
                  $results->execute();
                  if($results){
                      header('location:menu.php?message=deleted&&?page=1');
                  }
```

menu.php

```
if($typeuser == 'admin'){   
                        $item_per_page = 1;
                        $dbcon = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=laundry','root','');
                        $results = $dbcon->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM konsumen");
                        $results->execute();
                        $get_total_rows = $results->fetch();

                        //breaking total records into pages
                        $pages = ceil($get_total_rows[0]/$item_per_page);

                        if(isset($_GET["page"])){
                        $page_number = filter_var($_GET["page"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);

                             if(!is_numeric($page_number)){die('Invalid page number!<a href="?page=1"> Back! </a>');} //incase of invalid page number
                        }else{
                         $page_number = 1;
                        }

                        $position = (($page_number-1) * $item_per_page);

                        $results = $dbcon->prepare("SELECT * FROM konsumen ORDER BY kode_pemesanan ASC LIMIT $position, $item_per_page");
                        $results->execute();
                        while($row = $results->fetch()){
                             print_r ("<table>
                                 <tr>
                                 <td>Kode Pemesanan</td><td>:</td><td>".$row['kode_pemesanan']."</td></tr>
                                 <tr><td>Atas Nama</td><td>:</td><td>".$row['atas_nama']."</td></tr>
                                 <tr><td>Jumlah Baju</td><td>:</td><td>".$row['jmlhbaju']."</td></tr>
                                 <tr><td>Jumlah Celana</td><td>:</td><td>".$row['jmlhcelana']."</td></tr>
                                 <tr><td>Jumlah Jaket</td><td>:</td><td>".$row['jmlhjaket']."</td></tr>
                                 <tr><td>Jumlah Jas</td><td>:</td><td>".$row['jmlhjas']."</td></tr>
                                 <tr><td>Jumlah Dress</td><td>:</td><td>".$row['jmlhdress']."</td></tr>
                                 <tr><td>Pengurus Pesanan</td><td>:</td><td>".$row['penguruspesanan']."</td></tr>
                                 <tr><td>Status Pesanan</td><td>:</td><td>".$row['statuspesanan']."</td></tr>
                                 <tr><td>Total Pesanan</td><td>:</td><td>".$row['totalpesanan']."</td>
                                 </tr></table>
                                 <br>
                                 ");    
                        }
                        $min = 1;
                        if(isset($_GET["page"]) && $_GET["page"] > $min ){
                      $previous = $page_number - 1;
                      echo "<a href='?page=$previous'>&larr;Previous</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                    } else echo "<a href='?page=1'>&larr;Previous</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;";

                    echo "<a href='edit.php?page=$page_number'>Edit</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                    echo "<a href='delete.php?page=$page_number'>Delete</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;";

                                            if(isset($_GET["page"]) && $_GET["page"] < $pages ){
                      $next = $page_number + 1;
                      echo "<a href='?page=$next'>Next&rarr;</a>";
                    } else echo "<a href='?page=$pages'>Next&rarr;</a>";
                                        }



                }
```

Comment: There are so many things wrong here which explains why the answers received are so bad!  Please at least provide us with the `konsumen` table definition including the primary key.

Comment: sorry my lacks, so the konsumen table has kode_pemesanan as the primary key, atas_nama,jmlhbaju.jmlhcelana,jmlhjaket,jmlhjas,jmlhdress,penguruspesanan,statuspesanan,and totalpesanan columns, i display the konsumen table using pagination in menu.php and it shows good, it only can't delete the selected record, i think i can't reach the selected record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many issues with this but the main one is that the query you're trying to run makes no sense at all:

```
DELETE FROM konsumen ORDER BY kode_pemesanan ASC LIMIT :page_number
```

Not only are you not specifying a record to delete but your `DELETE` query looks more like a `SELECT` query with the `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`.

Your `echo "<a href='delete.php?page=$page_number'>Delete</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;";` link would need to be inside the fetch loop and use the key, not the page number:

```
echo "<a href='delete.php?key={$row['kode_pemesanan']}'>Delete</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;";
```

And of course you'd need to correct the `delete.php` to use that key.

Instead of `$page_number = $_GET['page'];`, you could put `$key = $_GET['key'];`, ideally do basic validation and then correct your PDO querying:

```
$results = $dbdit->prepare("DELETE FROM konsumen WHERE kode_pemesanan = :kode_pemesanan");
$results->bindValue(':kode_pemesanan', $key, PDO::PARAM_INT);

if($results->execute()){
    header('location:menu.php?message=deleted&&?page=1');
}
else { // you can do better than this but it's just to show how to properly deal with returned values
    die('error in delete query');
}
```

There may be other issues but I can't test this on your site to find them.

Comment: i edit my code, for using the primary key as the selected record, but still now working.. the record still appear in the menu.php and also in my phpmyadmin

Comment: i tried to edit the message=deleted into '.$key.'=deleted and it's not showing me the $key value , it's shows me menu,php?=deleted&&?page=1

Comment: yes, but it's still not working, and i edit the message just for testing which record i select but seems i'm not selecting any of the records

Comment: Did you check that the `key` assigned was sent properly and matches the record to delete?  If so, does the script result in an error or show that it worked?  Please put some effort in troubleshooting your work.  If I could do it for you it would already work.

Comment: but the script runs well @julie

Comment: i'm trying again to check the script from you it's all work!, and i'm curious must be it's all from my mistakes, so i change the position of the } in menu,php to include the buttons in the while statement thank you julie !!

Answer (score -1):

Try calling `$results->execute();` again after `PREPARING` your `delete` query statement.

```
$results = $dbdit->prepare("DELETE FROM konsumen ORDER BY kode_pemesanan ASC LIMIT :page_number");
$results->bindValue(':page_number',$page_number);
$results->execute();
if($results){
    header('location:menu.php?message=deleted&&?page=1');
}
```